# pyautogui unable to recognize app opened by subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a python-based GUI application running on Windows.
Pyautogui able to locate the button if I manually launch the application, for example, in CMD, run `python myapp.py`

However, when I included the app opening operation in my script using `subprocess.Popen`, pyautogui is no longer recognize the button

Here's my code snippet

```
open_myapp = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'myapp.py'],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
r = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(icon_locator.FILE_BTN)
print(r)
time.sleep(5)
```

Returns

```
None
```

If I comment out the subprocess, start `myapp` from Windows CMD manually, and rerun the code, I am able to get return position

```
Point(x=260, y=279)
```

Any ideas what's went wrong here?

Comment: You are calling `locateCenterOnScreen()` about a millisecond after launching the program.  It probably doesn't even have a visible window yet.  Basically, you have put the `sleep()` in the wrong place.

Comment: @jasonharper Hi, I have a `time.sleep(5)` in my actual script and I could see the app has been started before locating on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the *time.sleep(5)* after the print you want. You need to **put that command after the app opens and give it a time so that the script doesn't run before the app is visible on screen**. It's just like *Jasonharper* said in his comment.

It should be something like:

```
## whatever the command to open the app is ##
time.sleep(5)
print(r)
```

Also define 'r' at the top of your file, just because it's better.
That should do it.